# Sliding Window - findLongestSubString (please explain this piece of code/answer)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Now I have solved this algorithmic challenge myself but I would like someone to explain the answer below line by line please as I took it from someone else. I do NOT understand it at all and how the answers come to be, even after using pythonTutor.

Challenge: 
 Write a function called findLongestSubstring, which accepts a string and returns the length of the longest substring with all distinct characters.
Edit: I only do NOT understand the ABOVE CODE.

```
function findLongestSubstring(str) {
  let longest = 0;
  let seen = {};
  let start = 0;
 
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let char = str[i];
    if (seen[char]) {
      start = Math.max(start, seen[char]);
    }
    // index - beginning of substring + 1 (to include current in count)
    longest = Math.max(longest, i - start + 1);
    // store the index of the next char so as to not double count
    seen[char] = i + 1;
  }
  return longest;
}

// findLongestSubstring("thisisawesome"); // 6
// findLongestSubstring("thecatinthehat"); // 7
```

My solution:

```
function findLongestSubstring(str){
if (str.length === 0) return 0;
// track longest length
let longestLength;
// get first subArr 
let subStrArr = str.split("").slice(0,1);
// get first subArrLength
let subStrLength = subStrArr.length;
longestLength = subStrLength;
// variable for checking every character
let j = 0;
// for loop
for ( let i = 1; i < str.length; i++ ) { 
  // if current element don't exist in subArr
if (!subStrArr.includes(str[i])) {
subStrArr = str.split("").slice(j,i+1);
subStrLength = subStrArr.length;
}
// does exist
else {
  j++;
  i = j;
  subStrArr = str.split("").slice(i,i+1);
  subStrLength = subStrArr.length;
}
if (subStrLength > longestLength) longestLength = subStrLength;
}
return longestLength;
}

findLongestSubstring("rithmschool"); // 7
```

Comment: @Pointy I did it solve it myself but its different from this obviously. Not sure what you're trying to hint at really. Please give constructive comment nextime.
Edit: Also just because I took this code from someone else doesn't mean I wasn't able to solve it myself through my own code. There are always different answers to a specific problem.

Comment: @user1984 I assume this is a rhetorical question? You're not helping me here.

Comment: No, it isn't rhetorical question. By not stating the problem the posted code solves you make it much harder to decipher the algorithm and come up with helpful answers.

Comment: @user1984 I don't understand your comment. I think I tried my best to make a decent post. You're not being helpful buddy.

Comment: @GodOfProgramming to be honest, such algorithmic exercises are hard for me too. Paper and pencil should help you. If I were you I would draw each iteration step on a paper. In 90% cases it will halp you to understand.

Comment: @user1984 Okay I shall stop "antagonizing" everyone. I told you I did not understand your comments. So would you be so kind to explain again. I'm trying my best to learn :)

"question wasn't clear" I stated the challenge, problem ( not understanding the flow of the code at the very top ). What is so unclear?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Okay if you actually "scratch" an answer for me. I would be very grateful :)

Comment: I see you have had the problem statement in the question from the start. I missed it. Sorry for the confusion :-)

Comment: @GodOfProgramming please see this https://tsplay.dev/WYBBxw , I have commented each iteration. Hope it helps. I did not post an answer because of lack of time

Answer (score 0):

A substring with *unique* characters doesn't obviously have duplicate letters. So as we move forward in our string `str`, we keep track of the greatest index of all the characters that we have already met in `seen`. The greatest index of each letter is obviously the one we have seen last since we move from left to right.

Now, in your iteration, when you reach a letter that you find in `seen`, you need to set `start` to that character's index tracked by `seen` to avoid including both letters in your substring. We take the `max` because `start` of substring may already be higher because of another double letter that we met earlier:

```js
if (seen[char]) {
  start = Math.max(start, seen[char]);
}
```

Then we just look how long our current substring is and retain it if it's longer than our longest seen.

```js
longest = Math.max(longest, i - start + 1);
```

And at last we save the index of the character in `seen`

```js
seen[char] = i + 1;
```

The order of these operations is important. If we updated `seen` with the index of the char first then we couldn't check `seen` for the character and set `start` based on it.

Comment: I still don't get it. It's like I get it but I don't if you know what I mean. It's hard to pinpoint how the ```longest``` variable get its final answer at the end. Consistencies changes every few loops back and forth.

Comment: Don't worry, sometimes it takes a little bit of time. Come back to it in a couple of days if you have time and you'll see that it isn't that difficult. Also, `longest` takes the max length at each iteration. So, it isn't calculated at the end. It is calculated along the way. @Garados

Comment: I think my biggest confusion is when ```longest``` variable is incremented? Like for eg. when we see a repeat character, we increment ```long``` when we're not suppose to? but when we see a new character we don't increment? And even vice versa sometimes.

Comment: No, we never increment `longest`. Each iteration, before we update the dictionary `seen` we do `longest = Math.max(longest, i - start + 1);` to set `longest` to the new length, if and only if it is greater than the current `longest`. Maybe you are confused about this line `seen[char] = i + 1;`? Here we set the index of the current char to `i + 1`. This helps us to avoid double character next time when we see a similar character like `char`.

Comment: Okay my bad not "increment". I said wrongly. I mean how do I know when is ```longest = Math.max(longest, i - start + 1);``` <--- gonna be the NEW longest, meaning higher than the previous longest.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You don't know. that's why you do `Math.max`. You compare `longest` that we have had from before and what the current length is (`i - start + 1`), and put the greater one in `longest`. This means that if the previous one was bigger, we retain it.

Comment: ```i - start +1``` is current length of what? object? substring?

Comment: `i - start + 1` is the current length of the substring where the end is `i` (our current location and start is `start`. At the beginning we set `start = 0`, Whenever we reach a character that we have seen previously (by checking `seen[char]`), we set `start = Math.max(start, seen[char])`. This guarantees that there are no double letters in our current substring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239315/discussion-between-garados-and-user1984).

Comment: i - start + 1 <-- i just found out is the length between latest repeated character and i.
I mean, between "start" and i.
im so close to understanding how this works now... i need one more clarification.
im using pythontutor going through the code again. the argument is "thisisawesome".
when im going through 8th index, "e" char,
start is 4,
index 4-8 is "isawe",
which represents longest = 5,
which doesn't add up? because the object shows t,h,i,s,a,w which are so far our substring, not "isawe".
and t,h,i,s,a,w is 6 not 5.